# CORREÇÃO DE EMAIL COM SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Bom estou com vários emails com problema no final ex: hotmal sem o .com @gmail sem o .com, etc.
O que estou tentando fazer em banco de dados oracle, procuro por gmail.com com a função `regex_substr`, se eu não encontrar eu quero uso um `regexp_replace` para realizar a troca do mesmo, para vários provedores eu uso o `regxp_substr` para encontrar e se ele não encontrar troca.
Porem eu não consigo usar a função `regexp_replace` no `then`, alguém já viu isso? Procurei e não encontrei.

segue o código

```
SELECT

email,

CASE  WHEN TRIM(UPPER(regexp_substr(EMAIL,'GMAIL.COM'))THEN 
REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(EMAIL),'GMAIL','GMAIL.COM')
END EMAIL

FROM EMAIL
```

Comment: Pensou em uma function tratando caso a caso ?

Comment: Pensei ,porem tenho medo de usar function dentro do Banco e derrubar rsrs, sou estagiario ae ja vio..

Comment: Que erro ocorre ?

Comment: Era um erro de logica , onde eu não passava uma parametro . Segue o codigo para solução .
WHEN 
REGEXP_INSTR(UPPER(TRIM(UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(regexp_substr(desc_email,'@[^.]*'),'@','')))),'COM')<1 AND REGEXP_INSTR(UPPER(desc_email),'GMAIL')>0 AND NOT REGEXP_INSTR(UPPER(desc_email),'GMAILCOM')>0 AND NOT REGEXP_INSTR(UPPER(desc_email),'GMAIL.COM')>0  THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(DESC_EMAIL),'GMAIL','GMAIL.COM')
else email

Comment: @user162978, você responder sua própria pergunta com a solução acima.

Comment: @Gilson pode melhorar o título da sua pergunta? Lendo ela não é possível descobrir qual a sua dúvida

Comment: Alterei , caso tenha alguma dica posso melhorar

Comment: @Gilson pode acertar removendo as letras maiúsculas: "Correção de e-mail no SQL", ficaria  bem melhor. Mas ainda assim o seu título poderia ser mais técnico. Exemplo: "Não consigo usar a função regexp_replace com then. Como faço uma substituição com condição no Oracle?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu daria como sugestão utilizar outras ferramentas que o próprio SQL te oferece.

Ao invés de utilizar o `regexp_instr` e `regexp_replace`, 
procure utilizar funções mais simples, como  `substr`,`instr`,`like`

Fiz um exemplo que seria mais prático para entender e resolver esse problema:

```
SELECT CASE
         --emails corretos
         WHEN INSTR(';GMAIL.COM;GMAIL.COM.BR;HOTMAIL.COM;HOTMAIL.COM.BR;',';' || SUBSTR(EMAIL,INSTR(EMAIL,'@') +1 ) || ';') > 0 THEN
           email
       --emails incorretos
       ELSE
         SUBSTR(email, 0, instr(email, '@')) || CASE WHEN email LIKE '%GMAIL%' THEN 'GMAIL.COM' 
                                                      WHEN email LIKE '%HOTMAIL%' THEN 'HOTMAIL.COM' 
                                                      WHEN email LIKE '%OUTLOOK%' THEN 'OUTLOOK.COM' END
       END email
  FROM (SELECT TRIM(UPPER(email)) email FROM email);
```

Veja rodando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a0f765/247).

Dessa forma é só alterar a lista de domínios correto separados por ";" e ajustar o que deverá ser feito pra cada um dos domínios que apresentam.

Fica mais simples de dar manutenção.

Comment: Realmente, está bem mais simples. Obrigado, quebrei a cabeça um bom tempinho rsrs..

Answer (score 2):

Bom ,comecei a observa mais o código era um erro de lógica, onde eu não passava uma parâmetro. Segue o código para solução .

```
WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(UPPER(TRIM(UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(regexp_substr(desc_email,'@[^.]*'),'@','')))), 'COM') < 1 
 AND REGEXP_INSTR(UPPER(desc_email),'GMAIL')>0 AND NOT REGEXP_INSTR(UPPER(desc_email),'GMAILCOM') > 0 
 AND NOT REGEXP_INSTR(UPPER(desc_email),'GMAIL.COM')>0 THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(DESC_EMAIL),'GMAIL','GMAIL.COM') ELSE
```

E a partir disso vou replicando para outros provedores , porem tem muito mais detalhes a ver.. exemplos, quando tenho email exemplo@hotmail,com. ele não pega com vírgula então tem que criar uma linha de `regexp_replace` só para isso..